# Singly linked list c

Tags: c, structure, singly-linked-list

I have to write simple program using singly linked lists. For example I have 2 structures:

```
struct client
{
  char name[30];
  struct client *next;
};

struct item
{
  char name_item[30];
};
```

How could I using singly linked lists add multiple items to 1 client?

Comment: Yea , I tried but failed everytime. I tried to do it by adding struct item to client, pointer and creating node for both client and item. Probably one of those ways is right but i just didnt know how to execute it propely..

Comment: In question of the previous problem?

Comment: Well previous question was part necessary for my programming class project this is aswell. Overall i have to make smth like database, and well my programming skills and still pretty bad. Biggest problem so far are for my linked lists and as im on winter break right now I cant ask about things which i dont understand my teacher so im writing here..

Answer (score 1):

For singly linked lists, each "thing" has to have a single link to the next "thing".

Therefore, to create a singly linked list of your `item` structures, you need to modify the structure so that it includes a link to the next item, like this:

```
struct item {
   struct item *next;
   char name_item[30];
};
```

Normally you also need to keep track of the start of the list. For example, you might do this:

```
struct client {
  struct client *nextClient;
  char name[30];
  struct item *firstItem;
};
```

Then you might have a function to add an item to a client, like this:

```
void addItemToClient(struct client *client, struct item *item) {
    item->next = client->firstItem;
    client->firstItem = item;
}
```

This inserts the new item at the start of the list. Sometimes you want to insert the new item at the end of the list instead. For that you need to keep track of the last item (in addition to keeping track of the first item). This would end up a bit like this:

```
struct client {
  struct client *nextClient;
  char name[30];
  struct item *firstItem;
  struct item *lastItem;
};

void addItemToClient(struct client *client, struct item *item) {
    item->next = NULL;
    if(client->firstItem == NULL) {
        client->firstItem = item;
    } else {
        client->firstItem->next = item;
    }  
    client->lastItem = item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: if you need to have variable number of items, you can have your implementation like so (please allow me to paraphrase)

```
typedef struct item
{ 
  char name_item[30];
}item;

//list.h
typedef struct node{
    item* this_key;
    struct node* keys;
    struct node* next;
}node, *Node;
Node new_node(char*, char**, int);
void printList(Node);



//list.c
//...preprocessor directives, etc
Node new_node(char* key, char** keys, int num_keys){
    Node n = (Node)malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->this_key = NULL;
    n->next  = NULL;
    n->keys = NULL;
    if (!key){ //constructing a normal list
        int i = 0;
        Node curr;
        for (; i < num_keys;++i){
            if (n->keys == NULL){
                n->keys = new_node(keys[i],NULL,0);
                curr = n->keys;
            } else {
                curr->next = new_node(keys[i],NULL,0);
                curr = curr->next;
            }
        }
    } else { //constructing a key list
        n->this_key = (item*)malloc(sizeof(struct item));
        snprintf(n->this_key->name_item, 30, "%s", key);

    }
    return n;
}

void printList(Node n){
    if (!n) return;
    if (n->this_key){
        printf("%s\n",n->this_key->name_item);
        printList(n->next);
    }else if (n->keys) {
        printList(n->keys);
        printf("=====\n");
        printList(n->next);
    }
}

//main.c
//..same deal
int main()
{
    char** cs = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*5);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (;i < 5;++i){
        cs[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 31);
        for (j = 0;j < 30;++j){
            cs[i][j] = 'a';
        }
        cs [i][30] = 0;
    }
    Node n = new_node(NULL, cs, 5);
    printList(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if some clients had a huge number of items and others had just one or two?  That's the whole point of using linked lists rather than fixed-size arrays.

Comment: The destructor can be recursive as well; just remember to free everything malloc'ed

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct item {
  char name[30];
  struct item *next;
};

struct client {
  char name[30];
  struct client *next;
  struct item *headitem; 
};


int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    struct client *headcli=NULL, *newclient;
    struct item *it;

    /* add one client */ 
    newclient = calloc(1,sizeof(struct client));
    strcpy(newclient->name,"John");
    newclient->next = headcli;
    headcli=newclient; 

    /* add one item to this client */
    it = calloc(1,sizeof(struct item));
    strcpy(it->name,"Orange");
    it->next=newclient->headitem;
    newclient->headitem = it;

    /* add another item to this client */
    it = calloc(1,sizeof(struct item));
    strcpy(it->name,"Banana");
    it->next=newclient->headitem;
    newclient->headitem = it;

    /* add other client */ 
    newclient = calloc(1,sizeof(struct client));
    strcpy(newclient->name,"Mary");
    newclient->next = headcli;
    headcli=newclient; 

    /* add one item to this client */
    it = calloc(1,sizeof(struct item));
    strcpy(it->name,"Peach");
    it->next=newclient->headitem;
    newclient->headitem = it;

    /* print client names and items */
    for(newclient=headcli;newclient;newclient=newclient->next) {
        printf("name: %s\n", newclient->name);
        for(it=newclient->headitem;it;it=it->next) {
            printf("item name: %s\n",it->name);
        }
    }

    /* ... add more clients, items, etc. */

    /* When no longer needed,
     * all items in the list must be released:
     */

    while(headcli) {
        newclient=headcli->next;
        while(headcli->headitem) {
            it = headcli->headitem->next;
            free(headcli->headitem);
            headcli->headitem = it;
        }
        free(headcli);
        headcli = newclient;
    }
    return 0;
}
```